# Filter documents based off a condition

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, filter

The following are my relevant schemas:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        first: String,
        last: String
    },
    // Each user can have multiple roles
    roles: [{
        type: String,
        enum: ['admin', 'instructor', 'teachingAssistant', 'student']
    }]
});

UserSchema.methods.hasRole = function (role) {
    return this.roles.indexOf(role) > -1;
};

const CourseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    code: { type: String, required: true, unique: 1, uppercase: 1 },
    // Instructors teaching this course
    instructors: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
    // TAs teaching this course
    teachingAssistants: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
    // Students enrolled in the course
    students: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
});
```

On my admin system, I would like to show courses relevant to the logged-in user's roles:

- If the user is an admin, show all courses;
- If the user is an instructor, show only courses that they are teaching as an instructor;
- If the user is a TA, show only courses that they are teaching as a TA.

In the last two cases, a user is considered an instructor/TA of a course, if their user ID is in the course's list of instructors/TAs, respectively i.e. `course.instructors.indexOf(user._id) > -1` or `course.teachingAssistants.indexOf(user._id) > -1`.

Currently, this is how I am filtering courses for the logged-in user i.e. `req.user`:

```
exports.getCourses = (req, res) => {
    models.Course.find().sort('code').lean().exec((err, courses) => {
        res.render('admin/pages/courses', {
            bodyClass: 'courses',
            title: 'Courses',
            courses: _.filter(courses,  course => {
                return req.user.hasRole('admin') ||
                    course.instructors.indexOf(req.user.id) !== -1 ||
                    course.teachingAssistants.indexOf(req.user.id) !== -1;
            }) 
        });
    });
};
```

I was wondering if there is a way to move the filtering into the query itself (instead of waiting for all the results and then filter) ?

Answer (score 0):

you can, lets focus on this section

```
models.Course.find().
```

in the second parameter of **.find()**, you can specify what fields you want to fetch only.

**Scenario 1:** user role = admin

```
    var options = {};
    models.Course.find({}, options)
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't think this will help me. I am not trying to include/exclude fields, but include/exclude documents with one query.

Comment: then do that on the first parameter, then